# How to add to ListBox thread safe (via extension method)

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox

I would like to add an item to a listbox on a form, scroll it down to the last entry and then refresh it. I would like to do this inside a parallel ForEach loop.
To do this I found an extension method online and changed it to my needs. Now I receive the error message: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.". I understand the error is that a working thread tries to access to the ListBox. Indeed I can see that the main thread can update the ListBox before receiving the error. Also debugger tells me that the error is on line "int visibleItems..."
How can this be done?

```cs
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void AddItemThreadSafe(this System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb, object item)
    {
        int visibleItems = lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight;
        if (lb.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                lb.Items.Add(item);
                lb.TopIndex = Math.Max(lb.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0);
                lb.Refresh();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Items.Add(item);
            lb.TopIndex = Math.Max(lb.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0);
            lb.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to declare a variable "visibleItems" inside a delegate block and inside else clock. yes, code duplication, but should work

Comment: try  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]   above the function `AddItemThreadSafe`

Comment: I tried [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] but it doesn't solve the problem. I also moved "visibleItems" inside the delegate block, but that change results that the program freezes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are accessing the ClientSize properties through a thread other than the UI thread, which causes the Exception on the line `int visibleItems = lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight;`

If you prescind of visibleItems completely, you can get rid of the exception but it still wouldn't be thread safe code:

```
public static void AddItemThreadSafe(this System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb, object item)
{
    if (lb.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            lb.Items.Add(item);
            lb.TopIndex = Math.Max(lb.Items.Count - lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight + 1, 0);
            lb.Refresh();
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        lb.Items.Add(item);
        lb.TopIndex = Math.Max(lb.Items.Count - lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight + 1, 0);
        lb.Refresh();
    }
}
```

What you need is to make the adding of items, and the refresh, an atomic operation (don't allow the the execution to pause if the scheduler decides to give it a go to a another invoke).
You can use a lock for that:

```
private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

public static void AddItemThreadSafe(this System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb, object item)
{
    if (lb.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                // thread unsafe code
                lb.Items.Add(item);
                lb.TopIndex = Math.Max(lb.Items.Count - lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight + 1, 0);
            }        
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            // thread unsafe code
            lb.Items.Add(item);
            lb.TopIndex = Math.Max(lb.Items.Count - lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight + 1, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

But, if you run the code, with a Parallel.For such as

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (x) =>
{
   listBox1.AddItemThreadSafe(x);
});
```

The form will freeze. You need to ensure that the UI can render everything so far, so you can change it to:

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (x) =>
{
    listBox1.AddItemThreadSafe(x);
    Application.DoEvents();
});
```

And it will render the form correctly, like here:

[image: The form rendering the items in parallel]

Comment: This is just *awful* advice.  Spinning up tons of threads just to have all of them spend all of their time marshaling right back to the UI thread is going to waste *tons* of time for no productive gains.  You also shouldn't be using `DoEvents` like this; this is not an appropriate usage of the method and is only going to cause worlds of hurt for anyone following any of this advice.